# Table design for user likes relationship

Tags: mysql, database, performance, database-design

An example I have 4 tables:

- Users
- Photos
- Videos
- Audios

I want to create a response feature like Facebook like. Which better:

1. Create 1 table which has columns:

   > id (int)
   >   user_id(int)
   >
   > target_id(int)
   >
   > target_type(enum:video,photo,audio)
2. Create 1 table which has columns:

   > id (int)
   >   user_id (int)
   >   video_id (int)
   >   photo_id (int)
   >   audio_id (int)
3. create 3 tables for each type

> tablename: user_video_likes (column:user_id, video_id)
>
> tablename: user_photo_likes (column:user_id, photo_id)
>
> tablename: user_audio_likes (column:user_id, audio_id)

Usually, I use option 3, but after I join some projects with different designs like option 1 and 2 make me confused.

- Which one should I use that have better performance and query handling?
- I think option 3 is better but why I found some projects(which have higher senior status/experienced employee than me) with option 1 and 2 design?
- Is expensive to create more tables?

Comment: Option 1 is fine too but option2 is bad design. It is just easier to query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type 1 does not need `id`.  Instead, have

```
PRIMARY KEY(user_id, target_type, target_id)
```

I like type 2, but the indexes are messy; what do you have?  This may help:

```
PRIMARY KEY(user_id, id),   -- to cluster rows for a user
INDEX(id)   -- to keep AUTO_INCREMENT happy
```

For type 3, have this (etc)

```
PRIMARY KEY(user_id, video_id)
```

As for what is best, please provide the `SELECTs`.  Without them, I cannot critique which schema is best.